# I have been trying to detect images using yolo pre-trained model. AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python, attributes, dotnetnuke, yolo

I am trying to use yolo trained using pre trained model This is my code:

```
#PyTorch Variables for images
im_batches = list(map(prep_image, loaded_ims, [inp_dim for x in range(len(imlist))]))

#List containing dimensions of original images
im_dim_list = [(x.shape[1], x.shape[0]) for x in loaded_ims]
im_dim_list = torch.FloatTensor(im_dim_list).repeat(1,2)
```

This is the error I am getting, can someone help pls?

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-b6264ca0b0c5> in <module>()
----> 1 im_batches = list(map(prep_image, loaded_ims, [inp_dim for x in range(len(imlist))]))
      2 
      3 #List containing dimensions of original images
      4 im_dim_list = [(x.shape[1], x.shape[0]) for x in loaded_ims]
      5 im_dim_list = torch.FloatTensor(im_dim_list).repeat(1,2)

1 frames
<ipython-input-9-482a08216481> in letterbox_image(img, inp_dim)
      1 def letterbox_image(img, inp_dim):
      2     '''resize image with unchanged aspect ratio using padding'''
----> 3     img_w, img_h = img.shape[1], img.shape[0]
      4     w, h = inp_dim
      5     new_w = int(img_w * min(w/img_w, h/img_h))

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Comment: I can't help as I don't have any idea of python or yolo, but why is the question labelled with "dotnetnuke"?

Comment: somehow , you are not reading the image correctly which leads to a Nonetype image which has no shape attribute.